# Trouble validating whether or not an input field is empty and is required

Tags: jquery

I seem to be having trouble with checking if an input field is both empty and required and if so alerting a user. I currently have it working without looking to see if the input field is required, problem is an alert pops up when a non required field is left empty.

Here is the code:

```
    $('.close-and-show-next').click(function() {
      var empty = $(this).parent().find("input:visible").filter(function() {
      return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length && empty.closest('span').hasClass('required')) {
      //At least one input is empty
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.numberlabel').css('background-color','#FF0000');
      alert('One or more fields have been left blank. Please press EDIT to correct before pressing continue.');
    }
    });
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joseph_a_garcia/uuVjy/1/

Answer (score 0):

The span is not a parent of the input, so `closest()` won't work, you should be using `siblings()`

```
if (empty.length && empty.siblings('span.required').length) {...
```